# Conexão exclusiva no Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird

Estou tendo um problema em ambiente de produção, pois minha aplicação está tentando acessar de **forma exclusiva** o banco de dados e preciso contorna esse problema. Em debug isso não acontecia.

Retornando o erro:

'I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "C:\TESTE\DB.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo. '.

Basicamente já sei que esse é uma característica de usar a FDCLIENT incorporado conforme esse documentação.

[LInk](https://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/install2-win32-embed.html)

Porém preciso contorna isso e já sei que é possível.

Segue o código que chama a conexão a partir de um arquivo .INI

```
var
  vArquivo :TiniFile;
  caminho: String;
  user: String;
  pass: String;
  charset: String;
  DriverId : String;
  server: String;
  porta : String;
  tcp :String;
begin
 
 
  arquivo:=  ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
  arquivo:= arquivo + 'Ideiasp.ini';
  FDConexao.Params.clear;
  FDConexao.Connected:= FALSE;
  FDConexao.Params.Clear;
  {Carregameto do dados de parametro}
  vArquivo:= TIniFile.Create(arquivo);
  caminho:= vArquivo.ReadString('CONEXAO','DATABASE',caminho);
  user:= vArquivo.ReadString('CONEXAO','USERNAME',user);
  pass:= vArquivo.ReadString('CONEXAO','PASSWORD',pass);
  charset:= vArquivo.ReadString('CONEXAO','CharacterSet',charset);
  DriverId := vArquivo.ReadString('CONEXAO','DriverID',DriverId);
  server := vArquivo.ReadString('CONEXAO','Server',server);
  porta :=  vArquivo.ReadString('CONEXAO','Porta',porta);
  tcp:='TCPIP';
  VIdTabela := vArquivo.ReadString('TABELA','IdTabela',VIdTabela);

  
  FDConexao.Params.Values['Database']:= caminho;
  FDConexao.Params.Values['User_Name']:= user;
  FDConexao.Params.Values['Password']:= pass;
  FDConexao.Params.Values['CharacterSet']:= charset;
  FDConexao.Params.Values['DriverID']:= DriverId ;
  FDConexao.Params.Values['Server']:= server;
  FDConexao.Params.Values['Protocol']:= tcp;
  FDConexao.Params.Values['Pooled']:= 'false';
  FDConexao.Params.Values['SQLDialect']:= '3';
  FDConexao.Params.Values['GUIDEndian']:= 'Little';
  FDConexao.Params.Values['ExtendedMetadata']:='false';
  FDConexao.Params.Values['OpenMode']:= 'Open';
  FDConexao.Params.Values['CharLenMode']:= 'Chars';
  FDConexao.Connected:= TRUE;
```

Peço por favor ajudar pra fazer meu código funcionar melhor, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas coisas que podem causar isso

**1** IBexpert aberto acessando o arquivo.

**2** Não é um banco de dados válido.

**3** Tente reiniciar o serviço